# Unity Hub GUI rendering issue on macOS

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

I installed Unity Hub on macOS Monterey version 12.6 today and am having graphics issues.
It's a bit cut off from the GUI, there's a white space and it flickers when I want to click something.

[Unity Hub GUI Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuSYo.png)

I have the OS running on a VM because I don't have a MacBook and want to build my app for IOS.
So I don't know macOS that well either.
I did it some time ago and everything worked there.

Maybe the following info will help:
I also had the same problem with GitHub Desktop.
I fixed it by starting GitHub with the following command:
`GITHUB_DESKTOP_DISABLE_HARDWARE_ACCELERATION=1 open -a "GitHub Desktop"`

What I have already tried:

- Restart Unity Hub
- Restart VM

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through the same problem and managed to solve it by running the command:

```
/Applications/Unity\ Hub.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity\ Hub --disable-gpu
```

I created a shortcut via Automator.

Additional information, for Visual Studio Code:

```
/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron --disable-gpu
```

I hope it helps!